# Identifying duplicate pairs in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

The function `pd.duplicated()` gives you a boolean series indicating which rows in a dataframe are duplicated like below:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
dtype: bool
```

It however does not tell you which row the duplicates are duplicates of. 
Index 4 for example could be a duplicate of 0,1,2,3 or 5.

Is there a clever way of identifying which rows are duplicated and what these rows are duplicates of?

Answer (score 3):

Try groupby, size and filter for the ones with size above 1.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 2], [1, 3]], columns=["a", "b"])
>>> results = df.groupby(["a", "b"]).size()                                 
>>> results = results[results > 1]
>>> results
a  b
1  1    2
2  2    2
dtype: int64
```

You can also sort in order to get the most duplicated ones (if that interests you)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.groupby` to get the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6]})
df.groupby('a').groups
# {0: [5], 1: [0], 2: [1, 4], 3: [2, 3], 4: [6], 5: [7], 6: [8]}
```

Then decide on the values of that `dict` what you want to do...

Comment: it could be probably `df.groupby(list(df.columns)).groups` to have more generic solution

Answer (score 1):

> It however does not tell you which row the duplicates are duplicates of. Index 4 for example could be a duplicate of 0,1,2,3 or 5.

`.duplicated(keep=False)` discards this information about where the duplicate "groups" reside. I found two ways around this: one is using `.unique()` in a for loop, the other is `s.groupby(s)`

```py
s = pd.Series(["A","B","C","A","A","B","D","E"])

# what i want is a string like this

"""
0, 3 and 4: A
1 and 5: B
2: C
6: D
7: E
"""

string = ""
for val in s.unique():
    # here, we have access to the grouped values in s[s == val]
    string += do_something(s[s == val])

# this is another way
string = s.groupby(s).apply(lambda x: do_something_else(x.index))
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of pandas have a 'keep' option where you can specify which values you would want to mark. In this case, you would mark keep=False (and mark them all)

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1, 2, 4, 4, 5]})
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   x
0  1
1  2
2  4
3  4
4  5
In [4]: df.duplicated('x', keep=False)
Out[4]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```